# Why isn't the Django out-of-the-box password-reset feature working?

Tags: django

I am using Django 1.6. 
I have the following file in myApp/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html.

However, when I enter my email address in the form to send a reset password email, I get the following error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /auth/password_reset/
Could not parse the remainder: ',' from 'uid,'
```

What is wrong with the template below that causes the {% url %} tag to fail?

```
{% autoescape off %}
You're receiving this e-mail because you requested a password reset for your user account at {{ site_name }}.

Please go to the following page and choose a new password:
{% block reset_link %}
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm uidb36=uid, token=token %}
{% endblock %}

Your username, in case you've forgotten: {{ user.username }}

Thanks for using our site!

The {{ site_name }} team.

{% endautoescape %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using templatetags with several parameters, separate them by space.

Like `{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' uidb36=uid token=token %}` (notice that there is no , after "uid".

I think that is the solution.
See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/ for more info about custom templatetags and how they work.

Comment: How can I make this email look and feel like the other HTML emails from my application? I have a template called baseEmail.html which contains pretty headers and footers. But when I make this file extend baseEmail.html, I see all the HTML code right in the text of the email.